# Lag with ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, lag

I'm developing an app that displays information about wifistate, battery and other stuffs. To do this, I'm using fragments and each one has It's own ListView showing the info. When I slide from a fragment to another one, Listviews make the UI lag causing a bad user experience. How could I avoid this?
Thank You in advance.

**EDIT**:
This is my Adapter code:

```
public class GenericFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
          private List<Fragment> _fragments;
          public GenericFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
                   super(fm);
                   _fragments = fragments;
          }
          @Override
          public int getCount() {
                   return _fragments.size();
          }
          @Override
          public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                   return _fragments.get(position);
          }
          @Override
          public String getPageTitle(int position) {
                  return ((ITitledFragment) _fragments.get(position)).getTitle();
          }
}
```

Comment: Without you posting your code here, no one can help you.

Comment: Please share your viewpager adapter code.

Comment: Ok, I've posted it

Comment: How many items inside the `ListView`s are there?

Comment: About 7 for the first fragment and 8 for the second one. There are only 3 fragments for now